# How to pass JSON object from one feature file to another with Karate

Tags: json, api, rest, karate

I'm trying to pass a JSON object from one feature file to another feature file.So that I can use the JSON object as request body for an API call

Below is my code

```
Feature1.feature
 Scenario:__
 * def req = {"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}
 * def tempResponse = call read('Feature2.feature') {temp:req}

Feature2.feature
Scenario:___
Then print #(temp)
Give url '___'
And request #(temp)
When method POST
status 200
```

In my Featue2.feature file #(temp) does not have any JSON object.

Can I pass a JSON object from one feature file to another. Is there an alternate approach to this?

Comment: yes. read this please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karatecallsingle